# How to set .NET Error Pages for a specific folder in IIS 7?

Tags: .net, iis, custom-error-pages

Could custom error page be applied to to specific folder in IIS?

For example, my folder name is http://my.com/foobar, in IIS, I right clicked on the folder name >>> .Net Error Pages Icon >>> Add... >>> 404  >>>>> Absolute URL  >>http://my.com/error.html

This did not work. I checked in web.config file. There is nothing modified by IIS either. Am I doing something wrong?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I add to this:

I tried the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors>
            <error redirect="error.html" statusCode="403" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is no Go.

So I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="http://my.com/err.html" responseMode="Redirect" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This worked, but this was added to the web.config under root, is there any way to add  for a directory web.config?

Comment: [Create a Custom HTTP Error Response (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Hi, please see my update, could you advise? thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but the article mention that "*If Execute a URL on this site is selected, the path must be a URL relative to the root of the current site*"

Comment: i don't think it's a path issue, since the page is not being redirected at all. Yet I found another way and it worked. Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to directory web.config, and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
                                <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
                                <error statusCode="403" path="`___REDIRECT URL HERE________`" responseMode="Redirect" />
                                </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My question remaining: how is this different from the default way of doing it from IIS directly? Like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors>
            <error redirect="error.html" statusCode="403" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I heard this is working in IIS6 but not 7/7.5?