# How show different custom error pages for each area in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I designed a website that  have one area (manager) for administrators. In main web site i customized error pages easily in webconfig. with this:

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="400"/>
  <remove statusCode="401"/>
  <remove statusCode="403"/>
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <remove statusCode="408"/>
  <remove statusCode="409"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/400"/>
  <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/401"/>
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/403"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404"/>
  <error statusCode="408" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/408"/>
  <error statusCode="409" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/409"/>
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/500"/>
</httpErrors>
```

now i want to show administrators that are in manager area some different custom error pages (like their panels).

can someone tell me how can i do that?

**EDIT**:
I put a new web.config file in `/Areas/Manager` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"      defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="400"/>
  <remove statusCode="401"/>
  <remove statusCode="403"/>
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <remove statusCode="408"/>
  <remove statusCode="409"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/400"/>
  <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/401"/>
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/403"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/404"/>
  <error statusCode="408" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/408"/>
  <error statusCode="409" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/409"/>
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Manager/Error/500"/>
</httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

i even put httpErrors part in `~/Areas/Manager/Views/web.config`. but always for errors i see `/Error/ErrorCode` instead `/Manager/Error/ErrorCode` page.

Comment: How are Administrator's 404 message different from Customer's 404? Could you show two mock-ups side-by-side?

Comment: In my manager area i have a management panel(AdminLte) different menu, sidebar and footer etc. a completely different _Layout they have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new web.config that goes in the Admin/Manager folder.  That folder can then have it's own set of httpErrors that only apply to pages located in that folder.

Comment: do you mean /Areas/Manager folder? i did. but does not work.

Comment: Can you try adding the errorMode="Custom" to your web.config in the Manager folder?  - per StackOverflow question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487157/how-to-set-net-error-pages-for-a-specific-folder-in-iis-7   and this one here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487157/how-to-set-net-error-pages-for-a-specific-folder-in-iis-7